# Div Background disappear

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="position: relative;" >
        <div class="Shade" background="wood.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 17px;   left: 252px; width: 231px; height: 32px; color: #000; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;  border: 1px none #000000;" ><span class="welcome"><span class="goldtext">

                  พบกับผู้สร้างเว็บไซต์

           </span></span></div>
```

in dw it's work

but when I test in browser it's gone

Comment: any explain? what's your problem?

Comment: Use google translate to ask a question;)

Comment: first, do not use `inline` css! define styles for `.Shade` class , like this `.Shade {position: absolute; top: 17px;   left: 252px; width: 231px; height: 32px; color: #000; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;  border: 1px none #000000;}` | second check your path to image. | third, use `background-image` not `background`

Comment: you want to make a div background disaapear or the div itself

Comment: i can't add  images so it's hard to explain. my div background just dissapear  for no reason . i'm just test create a new div with no any parent but the background still don't show.

Comment: kk let me try thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that u need to write background in style

```
<div style="position: relative;" >
    <div class="Shade"  style="background:url('wood.jpg');position: absolute; top: 17px;   left: 252px; width: 231px; height: 32px; color: #000; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;  border: 1px none #000000;" ><span class="welcome"><span class="goldtext">

              พบกับผู้สร้างเว็บไซต์

       </span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution:
 u have mentioned "background" property at wrong place.
corrected code is as follows:

```
<div style="position: relative;" >
        <div class="Shade" style="background:url('wood.jpg');position: absolute; top: 17px;   left: 252px; width: 231px; height: 32px; color: #000; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;  border: 1px none #000000;" ><span class="welcome"><span class="goldtext">

                  พบกับผู้สร้างเว็บไซต์

           </span></span></div>
```

> make sure your image file will be located in directory where this html code containing file is located